# Joomla. Взаимодействие плагина с компонентом

Tags: joomla, плагин

Добрый день!
Есть компонент [helloworld](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Using_the_database), также есть плагин

```
class plgContentHelloworld extends JPlugin
{
public function onContentAfterDisplay($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    {       

    }
}
```

Подскажите, как вывести данные com_helloworld после статьи. Как взаимодействует плагин с компонентом. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: для начала укажите какая версия Joomla!

Comment: есть ли для вашего компонента модуль, который может выводить контент из вашего компонента?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Статья это компонент *com_content*, и в *Joomla!* на одной странице одновременно может выводиться только один компонент и сколь угодно модулей.
Поэтому вам как минимум нужен модуль а не компонент, если вы его хотите запихнуть в статью или после нее в какой то блок шаблона.
Плагин может обрабатывать данные на странице, получая текст статьи например.
Для вывода модуля в Joomla! есть специальный плагин *Content-Load Modules*. Который позволяет вывести в статье позицию, его надо включить в плагинах и в статье прописать строку типа {loadposition poziciya}

В свою очередь вам надо создать позицию poziciya, при настройках модуля, в Joomla! можно создать позицию с произвольным именем и прикрепить к ней любой модуль.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо! Я имел ввиду не вывод компонента, а получение данных из модели и вывод этих данных в onContentAfterDisplay. Например есть таблица с комментариями к статье, и эти комментарии я хочу выводить после статьи

Comment: Дело в том что тут просто так не получится добраться из плагина до модели вашего компонента. Тут вам надо заново писать класс который бы получал данные из таблицы вашего компонента или в компоненте оформить вашу модель в виде синглтона и обращаться заинклюдив ваш класс из папок компонента. Тут что модуль, что плагин в одинаковой ситуации, насколько мне известно. В качестве рекомендации могу посоветовать изучить как подобное сделано в компоненте и его модулях/плагинах K2 http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/k2

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Так и буду пробовать